# Not able to access service from the public ip in kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, devops, kubernetes-pod

I am using kubernetes  and run one service. Service is running and is showing in service. But i am not able to access it from the public ip of the instance. Below is my deployment file.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: apache-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: apache
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  type: NodePort

---
apiVersion: apps/v1 # for versions before 1.9.0 use apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: apache-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: apache
  replicas: 2 # tells deployment to run 2 pods matching the template
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: apache
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: apache
        image: mobingi/ubuntu-apache2-php7:7.2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

Here is my list of service.

```
NAME             TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
apache-service   NodePort    10.106.242.181   <none>        80:31807/TCP   9m5s
kubernetes       ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP        11m
```

But when i check the same service from the follwing telnet with the public ip of cluster and node. It is not responding.

```
telnet public-ip:31807
```

Any type of help will be appreciable.

Comment: is this working curl http://10.106.242.181

Comment: Did you deploy it locally (e.g. Minikube, microk8s) or on managed cluster (EKS, GKE)?

Comment: Basic checks: If you `kubectl get pods`, is it Running? If you `kubectl describe service apache-service`, is it connected to the pod? Does your host or network have any sort of firewalling setup that would block connections by default (`iptables`, AWS security groups, ...)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by cluster IP? Do you mean the node that acts as kunernetes master? It won't work if you use master IP. Because masters don't have deployments scheduled due to security concerns.

Exposing a service via nodeport means that the service listens to a particular port in each of the worker nodes. So you can access the kunernetes worker nodes with the nodeports and get response. However if you created the cluster using cloud providers like aws, the worker nodes security groups are secured. Probably, you need to edit the security groups of worker nodes to access the service.

Comment: issue has been resolved. I checked from node ip and open firewall rule for the instance. it works. Thanks for your help.